# Update time every second

Tags: java, android, countdown

I need to update time every second on a countdown timer which counts down to Christmas. 
How do I update the time in my text view.I do not have the code in the onCreate method.

here is some of my code. When I run the code it gives the exact time, but it does not countdown live on screen. Any ideas?
Edit: the readThisPeriod is for calculating the time left until Christmas.

```
  public void DateCalculator() {
      Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
      thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 0-11 so 1 less
      thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);
      System.out.println(thatDay.getTime());
      ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = 

      Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
      scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ReadThisPeriod(thatDay), 0, 1, 
      TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      long diff = (thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
      long days = diff / (60 * 60 * 24);
      long hours = diff / (60 * 60) % 24;
      long minutes = diff / 60 % 60;
      long seconds = diff % 60;

      daysBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s1Days);


      daysBox.setText("" + "" + days + "" + hours + "" + minutes + "" + seconds + " );
}
```

Comment: You need to give more information about the `ReadThisPeriod` class, but my guess is that you need to pass a reference to the daysBox instance so that the thread (`ReadThisPeriod`) can set the text, not the main thread. You're updating once in the constructor call for DataCalculator.

Comment: Thank you, the ReadThisPeriod simply calculates the time difference. I am just calling a class. How can I update every second?

Comment: duplicate of a same question by yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327721/how-to-update-time-every-second-in-java-emulator/27327924#27327924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView daysBox;
    private boolean running;
    private Calendar thatDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        daysBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_day);

        thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 0-11 so 1 less
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);

        startDateCalculator();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        running = false;
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        running = true;
    }


    private class CountdownTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                publishProgress();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... res) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(res);

            long diff = (thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
            long days = diff / (60 * 60 * 24);
            long hours = diff / (60 * 60) % 24;
            long minutes = diff / 60 % 60;
            long seconds = diff % 60;


            daysBox.setText("" + "" + days + "d " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ");
        }
    }

    public void startDateCalculator() {

        new CountdownTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I insert the set text in onCreate?

Comment: onCreate is executed only once. Since you want the daysBox to be updated every second, its update logic should be put in the ReadThisPeriod.run() as it is called every second

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Where should I place the ReadThisPeriod.run()?

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate() method takes a Runnable as first parameter. You put "new ReadThisPeriod(thatDay)" as parameter, so it should already have implemented "Runnable" interface. And you'll be forced to implement "run()" method in "ReadThisPeriod" class. So you could just put the setText() inside the "run()" method, with runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run(){  ... }});

Comment: Thanks very much! I have tried that, but the code does not like when I put in the setText into the run. Am I missing something in the onCreate? Or could I send you my code in full?

Comment: this one is working, although I can see the time formatting is strange

Comment: Could I send you an email? It is really frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Start a `CountDownTimer` :

```
long endTime = thatDay.getTimeInMillis();
new MyCountDownTimer(endTime-System.currentTimeMillis(),1000).start();
```

Here you go:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
  super(startTime, interval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
  textView.setText("Happy Christmas!");
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millis) {
  int SECOND = 1000;
  int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
  int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
  int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
  StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
  if (millis > DAY) {
    text.append(millis / DAY).append(" days ");
    millis %= DAY;
  }
  if (millis > HOUR) {
    text.append(millis / HOUR).append(" hours ");
    millis %= HOUR;
  }
  if (millis > MINUTE) {
    text.append(millis / MINUTE).append(" minutes ");
    millis %= MINUTE;
  }
  if (millis > SECOND) {
    text.append(millis / SECOND).append(" seconds ");
    millis %= SECOND;
  }
  textView.setText(text);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  long diff = (thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
  long total=diff;

            mTimer=new CountDownTimer(total, 1000) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    diff--;  
                    daysBox.setText(convertSecondToHHMMString(diff));
                 }

                public void onFinish() {
                    System.out.println("Happy Chrismas");

                 }
              }.start();


  private String convertSecondToHHMMString(long secondtTime){

     TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
     df.setTimeZone(tz);
     String time = df.format(new Date(secondtTime*1000L));

     return time;
 }
```